# Making text bold on a listview to a specify word dynamically

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, spannable

I am trying to put color and bold up on a word that matches the word from a sentence in ArrayList items/value. what I have done so far is as below... so I have a String variable called filter "Hello" now I want to iterate through ArrayList itemList and find "Hello" from ArrayList items and make it bold and blue.

```
String filter = "Hello";
    String itemValue = "I just want to say Hello world! Hello";

    itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        itemList.add("I just want to say Hello world! Hello");
    }
    sentence = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int j=0; j<itemList.size(); j++)
    {
        int startPos = itemList.get(j).toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(filter.toLowerCase(Locale.US));
        int endPos = startPos + filter.length();

        if (startPos != -1) // This should always be true, just a sanity check
        {
            Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(itemValue);
            ColorStateList blueColor = new ColorStateList(new int[][] { new int[] {}}, new int[] { Color.BLUE });
            TextAppearanceSpan highlightSpan = new TextAppearanceSpan(null, Typeface.BOLD, -1, blueColor, null);

            spannable.setSpan(highlightSpan, startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            tv.setText(spannable);

            sentence.add(itemValue);

            ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              //      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, sentence);
            MyPerformanceArrayAdapter adapter = new MyPerformanceArrayAdapter(this, spannable, counterArrayList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else
            tv.setText(itemValue);                 
    }
```

its not working can you please help me

Comment: You should use a custom ListView adapter

Comment: MyPerformanceArrayAdapter is my custom listview adapter. How can I do that can you help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make another constructor passing it another argument `String filter` which will contain your string to be bold.

Assign it to another data member in the `arrayAdapter`

Now while displaying the view,
You should replace the `filter` in every sentence. i.e. `sentence.replace(filter, "<b>" + filter + "</b>")`

And show it into the textView like this `myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sentence));`

**After that all you have to do is Reset Adapter**