# How to bold specific word in listview android

Tags: android, listview, text, styles

I'm trying to bold the specific text in listview that contains ":". I want to bold the word underlined in the image below that contains ":" but I'm having trouble getting all the message. Please see my current code below.
I appreciate for your any response.

[image]

```
ArrayList<String> list_items = new ArrayList<String>();
public  void listview_refresh(){
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_items);

    ContentResolver cResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = cResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null,null,null,"date desc");
    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
    do{
        str = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) ;
        arrayAdapter.add(str);

        String[] separated = str.split(":");
        String separate = separated[1];

        arrayAdapter.replaceAll(separate, "<b>" + separate + "</b>"); //errorline

    }while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: check if you have an answer here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30546555/13685592

Comment: I already check this but where did the myTextview came from? custom listview? myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sentence)); @KalanaChinthaka

Comment: @DagzRV you are setting the text somewhere using this adapter where is the code ? on that textView you should call yourTextView.setText(Html.formatHtml(yourStringfromAdapterHere));

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgiok.jpg Thanks for your response this textview is connected to my lisview but my textview.xml is on the separate xml and also did not use textview to bold the text I use listview  @KalanaChinthaka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add string as Html within the adapter list. I have modified your code and added `Html.fromHtml(..)` to make text to use HTML code within.

```
ArrayList<String> list_items = new ArrayList<String>();
public  void listview_refresh(){
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_items);

ContentResolver cResolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor smsInboxCursor = cResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null,null,null,"date desc");
int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
do{
    str = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) ;
    
    String[] separated = str.split(":");
    String separate = separated[1];

    str = str.replaceAll(separate, "<b>" + separate + "</b>"); //errorline
    arrayAdapter.add(Html.fromHtml(str));
}while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Still the word doesn't bold , please help @Ashish Karn

Comment: I have added Html.fromHtml(..) while adding to adpter please check again.

Comment: Thank you so much I get it now! @Ashish Karn

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiCrn.png This is looks like now @Ashish Karn , but I have also one question I observed that those bold and underline string has not been properly align same with the other list

Comment: What's that one problem?